# Example of BV vector field $c$ without bounded divergence such that $u$ is bounded where $u_t + div(cu) = 0$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory, hyperbolic-pde

What is an example of vector field $c: \mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R^N$ with $c \in L^1(\mathbb{R}_+, BV(\mathbb R^N))$ without bounded divergence $div_x c$ but such that there exists a distributional solution $u$ of $$u_t + div(cu) = 0$$ with
$$\alpha \le u \le \beta, $$
$\alpha, \beta >0$?

Comment: Would a local statement make you happy? In other words are you interested in large $t$, large $|x|$, or is it really important for you that the bounds on $u$ hold globally in $R_+\times R^N$? Would you be happy e.g. with $c\in L^1_{loc}(R_+,BV)$?

Comment: @leomonsaingeon Yes, I'd be interested in a local example too.